# Gradle build failing when firebase dependecies added

Tags: firebase, gradle, dart, flutter

I want to use Firebase for my application, but whenever I add a firebase specific dependency (ex: "cloud_firestore:" or "firebase_analytics: ^0.3.3") I cannot build the app. When I do flutter run I receive the following output:

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       4.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                   19.1s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4]], but
resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Gradle build failed: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_remote_config#android-integration) you need to add *Android dependencies* if you want to run *Firebase on Android*.

In your `build.gradle` **project level** file, you need to add:

```
dependencies {
  // other dependencies might already be here

  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
}
```

To your **app level** *`build.gradle`*, add *at the very bottom*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*Not every* Firebase plugin page for *Dart* has this information. [Another great source is this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5), as it shows how to integrate with *Android* and *iOS*.

Also, when using *Android*, make sure that your device has **Google Play services** installed.

Comment: I had already done this, in addition to this following the instructions whilst setting up the firebase android project I added:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
to the app level build.gradle file, which when removed/commented out seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @Marko So, what I said applies and you only added too much?

Comment: the issue was apparently a bit deeper than that, my fix wasn't really a fix, this video covers it good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bROui4ID9_Q